# How to add white space between 2 variables in PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace

I am trying to add white space while i concatenate 2 variables contains string.

I variable getting from session it has already space.

But when i try to add space before second string it displays **%A0** in HREF.

I only need space cause i need to compare those variables using **==** and i it breaking condition.

Here is my code.

```
$groupObj->setGroupCreator($customer->getFirstname().$customer->getLastname());
```

I don't need space between **Second Second**.

Check below snapshot.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNMrA.png)

I tried multiple codes but its not working for me.

```
$groupObj->setGroupCreator($customer->getFirstname().'&nbsp;'.$customer->getLastname());

$groupObj->setGroupCreator($customer->getFirstname() .' '. $customer->getLastname());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this `."  ".`

Comment: Did try but same problem. You can check last line of code i added in question.

Comment: In last line of code there are single quotes. I am saying about double quotes

Comment: @Mr.Developer - why do you think double quotes will be any different to single quotes with a single space?

Comment: @Mr.Developer, I also tried bro. but not working.

Comment: So you want to add a space inside your href?

Comment: @hungrykoala, Exactly You got it man.

Comment: Why do you want to add space to an href tag? URL can't have space and it will just be encoded by the browser when you click on it.

Comment: @hungrykoala, Please check given snapshot.

Comment: I still don't get why you need a space in there. The snapshot doesn't explain much

Comment: @hungrykoala, When we hover over href it will display link. Than according to screenshot you can see first Second Second have space but last have %A0 i dont need %A0. I need space too. But in inspect element there is space.

Comment: Use popover instead if you just want to display something on hover. The space will be converted if you hover on the link directly since that's how it works.